# UnauthorizedError: invalid algorithm express-jwt

Tags: node.js, auth0, json-web-token, express-jwt

I am displaying some data on my website which returns from node server. It's works perfectly until today. Now I am getting below error on my server console when I go to my web page. I use `Auth0` for signin in users.

```
UnauthorizedError: invalid algorithm
    at C:\workspace\New\MyApp\node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:100:22
    at C:\workspace\New\MyApp\node_modules\express-jwt\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\index.js:155:18
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem. I use Auth0 for signin in users. You have to check the algorithm type.

**If you're using Auth0** then go to

*Client -> Settings -> Advanced Settings -> OAuth*

and check the algorithm type. It has to be HS256.

**If you're not using Auth0** then check the algorithm type also.

Answer (score 21):

HS256 is less secure because it is symmetric, (the same secret is shared between the client and server). See this question: [RS256 vs HS256: What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239051/rs256-vs-hs256-whats-the-difference)

You can maintain RS256 by using the [node-jwks-rsa](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa) module to retrieve the signing key:

```
import jwt from 'express-jwt'
import jwksRsa from 'jwks-rsa'

const secret = jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
  cache: true,
  rateLimit: true,
  jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
  jwksUri: 'https://<YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN>/.well-known/jwks.json',
})

const jwtCheck = jwt({
  secret: secret,
  audience: <YOUR_AUTH0_AUDIENCE_OR_CLIENT_ID>,
  issuer: 'https://<YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN>/',
  algorithms: ['RS256'],
})

app.use(jwtCheck)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this

```
expressJwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ['sha1', 'RS256', 'HS256'],
})
```

Comment: Why would this help?

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below in your expressJwt param():

```
algorithms: ['sha1', 'RS256', 'HS256'],   


Copy the algorithms and change/paste it on your function this methods helps me in postman, paw, robo 3t
```

Comment: that's basically the same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64521333/7329832), and doesn't add anything new but raises the same question: Why would this help?