# JWT is issuing the same token

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jwt

I am making a rest API with `Jersey`. I am using `java-jwt`(https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) for my token generation work. Please check the below code.

**UserJSONInfo** - REST methods class

```
@Path ("/user_info")
public class UserInfoJSONService 
{
    @POST
    @Path("/authenticateUser")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response authenticateUser(Credentials credentials)
    {
        UserInfoService service = new UserInfoService();

        try{
        UserInfo authenticateUser = service.authenticateUser(credentials.getUserName(), credentials.getPassword());
        String generateToken = service.generateToken(AuthKey.authorizationSecret);

        Authentication auth = new Authentication();
        auth.setIdUser(authenticateUser.getIduser());
        auth.setToken(generateToken);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(auth).build();
        //return authenticateUser;
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (JWTCreationException ex) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserInfoService** - Service Layer

```
public class UserInfoService {

    private static UserInfoDAOInterface userDAOInterface;

    public UserInfoService() {
        userDAOInterface = new UserInfoDAOImpl();
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        Session session = userDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        return session;
    }

    public Transaction getTransaction(Session session) {
        Transaction transaction = userDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
        return transaction;
    }



    public UserInfo authenticateUser(String userName, String password)
    {
        return authenticate(userName, password);
    }

    private UserInfo authenticate(String userName, String password) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        Session session = userDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        UserInfo user = new UserInfo();

        try {
            transaction = userDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
            user = userDAOInterface.authenticate(userName, password, session);
            transaction.commit();
//        } catch (Exception ex) {
//            //ex.printStackTrace();
//            System.out.println("OK");
//        
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return user;
    }

    public String generateToken(String secret) throws JWTCreationException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        Token token = new Token();
        return token.issueTokenHMAC256(secret);
    }

}
```

**AuthKey** - Simply contains the `secret`

```
public interface AuthKey {
    public static String authorizationSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ExampleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.ExampleServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ExampleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ExampleServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I have maintained my token generation classes as another java project and imported it here as a library (I am using Netbeans). Below is the code

```
package com.xyz.security;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTCreationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTVerificationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
public class Token {

    /**
     * Generate the HMAC256 Token
     * @param secret
     *          Secret to generate the token
     * @return 
     *      Token as a String
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     *      UTF-8 encoding not supported
     * @throws JWTVerificationException 
     *      Invalid Signing configuration / Couldn't convert Claims.
     */
    public String issueTokenHMAC256(String secret) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JWTCreationException
    {

        String token="";
        try {
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secret);
            token = JWT.create()
                    .withIssuer("auth0")
                    .sign(algorithm);


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {
    //UTF-8 encoding not supported
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JWTCreationException exception) {
    //Invalid Signing configuration / Couldn't convert Claims.
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return token;
    }


    /**
     * Validate a HMAC256 Token
     * @param token
     *          Token you need to validate
     * @param secret
     *          Secret used to generate the token
     * @return
     *          Returns `true` if token is valid.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     *          UTF-8 encoding not supported
     * @throws JWTVerificationException 
     *          Invalid Signing configuration / Couldn't convert Claims.
     */
    public boolean validateTokenHMAC256(String token, String secret) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JWTVerificationException
    {       
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secret);
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                .withIssuer("auth0")
                .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, everytime I generate the `token` when a user login, I am getting the same `token`. I am using `POSTMAN` to check REST methods, I opened 3 tabs and made a login attempt for 3 different users. The issue is I am getting the same token! Is this is correct or something wrong? In that case how can I fix it?

Comment: How did you generate this "authorizationSecret" in  "AuthKey" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### What authentication scheme based on tokens is about

In an authentication scheme based on tokens, the token becomes a credential of the user. Hard credentials such as username and password are exchanged for a token that must be sent in each request then the server can perform authentication/authorization. Tokens can be valid for a short amount of time, can be revoked, can carry scope details (what can be requested with the token), etc.

With a token, you must be able to identify the user who is targeting your API. Hence it makes no sense having a single token for all authenticated users.

### Addressing your issue

Once you are using JWT, you could have a claim with the username. Also consider adding an expiration date for you token ([`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) claim). You don't want your​ token to be valid forever, do you?

With [java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt), use the following:

```java
try {

    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");
    Date expirationDate = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().plusMinutes(60).toInstant());
    String token = JWT.create()
                      .withExpiresAt(expirationDate)
                      .withClaim("username", username)
                      .sign(algorithm);

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
    // UTF-8 encoding not supported
} catch (JWTCreationException e){
    // Invalid signing configuration / Couldn't convert claims
}
```

When verifying the token, you'll be able to get the `username` claim and know who you issued the token for:

```java
try {

    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");
    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
    DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);

    Claim usernameClaim = jwt.getClaim("username");
    String username = usernameClaim.asString();

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
    // UTF-8 encoding not supported
} catch (JWTVerificationException e){
    // Invalid signature/claims
}
```

### Handling token refreshment with JWT

Accept *only* valid (an non-expired) tokens for refreshment. It's responsability of the client to refresh the tokens before the expiration date indicated in the [`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) claim.

To avoid a token from being refreshed indefinitely, you could keep the track of the token refreshment by adding two claims to your token (the claim names are up to you):

- `refreshLimit`: Indicates how many times the token can be refreshed.
- `refreshCount`: Indicates how many times the token has been refreshed.

So only refresh the token if the following conditions are true:

- The token is not expired (`exp >= now`).
- The number of times that the token has been refreshed is less than the number of times that the token can be refreshed (`refreshCount < refreshLimit`).

And when refreshing the token:

- Update the expiration date (`exp = now + some-amount-of-time`).
- Increment the number of times that the token has been refreshed  (`refreshCount++`).

Once the token is signed and the signature is verified on server side, the content of the token cannot be tampered by the client.

Alternatively to keeping​ the track of the number of refreshments, you could have a claim that indicates the *absolute expiration date*. Before that date, any number of refreshments are acceptable.

Another approach involves issuing a separate long-lived refresh token that is used to issue short-lived JWT tokens.

The best approach depends on your requirements.

### Handling token revocation with JWT

If you want to revoke tokens, you must keep the track of them. You don't need to store the whole token on server side, store only the token identifier (that must be unique) and some metadata if you need. For the token identifier you could use [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122).

The [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim should be used to store the token identifier on the token itself. When validating the token, ensure that it has not been revoked by checking the value of the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim against the token identifiers you have on server side.

For security purposes, revoke all the tokens for a user when they change their password.

---

<sup>For more details on token-based authentication in JAX-RS, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227).</sup>

Comment: Thanks. When validating, the same could go into my `validateTokenHMAC256()` as well right?

Comment: Thank you. I also wanted to ask, instead of doing like `JWT.create().withClaim........` and so on, it would be very customizable lf we get a `JWT` object and continue right? Then it would be like `jwtobject.withClaim....` .I am on phone so can't check, but this is possible isn't it?

Comment: @PeakGen Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Is there anything wrong with the approach described above? That's how the API you are using works.

Comment: Thanks. Everything is working fine. Another question, when token is expired, how can I handle it? The user has to login go back to login screen and login in every hour?

Comment: @PeakGen If a request is performed with an invalid token, the server should respond with a `403` status code and the client should handle that (example, showing the login page). You also can allow your clients to refresh their tokens. There's no standards for that, but I updated my answer with what I usually do.

Comment: Thanks. I made another question and I am having an answer there but your input also highly appreciated. Link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090518/how-to-properly-handle-a-jwt-refresh