# What's the meaning of the "kid" claim in a JWT token?

Tags: token, jwt

I generated a JWT and there are some claims which I understand well, but there is a claim called `kid` in header. Does anyone know what it means?

I generated the token using auth0.com

Comment: Refer this Url for solution ;-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278051/why-is-jwtdecode-returning-status-kid-empty-unable-to-lookup-corr

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`kid` is an optional header claim which holds a key identifier, particularly useful when you have multiple keys to sign the tokens and you need to look up the right one to verify the signature.

Once signed, a JWT is a JWS.  Consider the definition from the [RFC 7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515):

> [**4.1.4.  "kid" (Key ID) Header Parameter**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.4)
>
> The `kid` (key ID) Header Parameter is a hint indicating which key
> was used to secure the JWS.  This parameter allows originators to
> explicitly signal a change of key to recipients.  The structure of the
> `kid` value is unspecified.  Its value MUST be a case-sensitive
> string.  Use of this Header Parameter is OPTIONAL.
>
> When used with a JWK, the `kid` value is used to match a JWK `kid`
> parameter value.

Comment: So it means that kid parameter can be used with HS256 algorithm only? right?

Comment: this answer is objectively correct, but sometimes its useful to keep track of the wrong answers out there - https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/813

Comment: @AmanGupta What makes you think only `HS256` has key-identifiers? Or that _only_ `HS256` use-cases require key lookup/identification?

Comment: Also good to mention https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7638 which is the standard some tools uses to calculate kid.

Answer (score 19):

The `kid` (key ID) claim is an optional header claim, used to specify the key for validating the signature.

It is described here: http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-jones-json-web-token-01.html#ReservedHeaderParameterName

Comment: Documentation drafts shouldn't be used as reference when the final version of the documentation is available. The `kid` claim has been moved from the JWT to the JWS and JWE specifications.