# I need to manage jwt secret keys individually for each user?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I implemented jwt authentication using the jsonwebtoken module. But do I need to create and manage arbitrary secret keys for each user when generating and verifying jwt tokens? Is there a difference between managing secret keys separately for each user and generating and verifying jwt tokens with one secret key?

Answer (score 6):

No, you use a single secret key to sign your tokens. This is because when the token comes back to you in a request, you need to be able to decode the token, and at this point you don’t know whether a genuine user is sending your token, because you haven’t verified it yet.

Use a single key to sign and verify your tokens, and remember to keep it safe.

Comment: Technically nothing stops you from parsing the header and/or the payload of a JWT token _before_ checking the signature. However the token cannot be trusted at this stage.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Rothschild, Cassio Mazzochi Molin

Answer (score 4):

No, you definitely don't need a key per user. A single key is enough for all users in most of situations.

If you want to, you can have a set of different keys and rotate them periodically to sign the tokens. In this situation, use the [`kid`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.4) header claim to hold a key identifier and then use it to look up the right key to verify the token. See more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870513/1426227).

Comment: Thank you so much!! Cassiio  Mazzochi Molin

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a difference between managing secret keys separately for each user and generating and verifying jwt tokens with one secret key?

The short answer is no, as far as a JWT is concerned a key is a key.

The long answer is *it depends*. The purpose of the JWT secret is to ensure the integrity of the message, generally this is something you would do at issuer (server) level as a way of verifying the origin of the message. In layman's terms, if the server can verify the signature then it can trust the contents.

User-level secrets move the trust down a level in the sense that you don't care which server generated the message but rather which *user* did. In a typical authentication token scenario it's really more server trust you want.