# How to have multiple jwt-secrets in a postgrest config file

Tags: postgrest

I am using PostgREST API on top of my postgresql database.

How do I have multiple jwt-secrets in the same config file?  I have multiple users that need to authenticate to my API server.

Answer (score 1):

PostgREST only supports one JWT secret for a single instance.

I don't think you need a secret for each user though. For example, the answers in [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112014/i-need-to-manage-jwt-secret-keys-individually-for-each-user) support this. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115371/17265105) suggests using a `"kid"`,  which are used in [JSON Web Key Sets](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets) and can be implemented in PostgREST with [asymmetric keys](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/references/auth.html?highlight=jwt#asymmetric-keys).