# "kid" empty, unable to lookup correct key (JWT with PHP)

Tags: php, jwt

I am trying to Implement the JWT with PHP following this tutorial:
https://www.w3jar.com/how-to-implement-the-jwt-with-php/

and so far i am able to get the token but when i try to decode the token i face this error:

```
"kid" empty, unable to lookup correct key
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require 'JwtHandler.php';
$jwt = new JwtHandler();

$token = $jwt->jwtEncodeData(
    'http://localhost/php-auth-api/',
    array("name" => "John", "email" => "john@email.com", "id" => 21)
);

echo "<strong>Your Token is -</strong><br><div><code>$token</code></div>";
?>
```

JwtHandler.php:

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class JwtHandler
{
protected $jwt_secrect;
protected $token;
protected $issuedAt;
protected $expire;
protected $jwt;

public function __construct()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $this->issuedAt = time();

    $this->expire = $this->issuedAt + 3600;

    $this->jwt_secrect = "this_is_my_secrect";
}

public function jwtEncodeData($iss, $data)
{

    $this->token = array(
        "iss" => $iss,
        "aud" => $iss,
        "iat" => $this->issuedAt,
        "exp" => $this->expire,
        "data" => $data
    );

    $this->jwt = JWT::encode($this->token, $this->jwt_secrect, 'HS256');
    return $this->jwt;
}

public function jwtDecodeData($jwt_token)
{
    try {
        $decode = JWT::decode($jwt_token, $this->jwt_secrect, array('HS256'));
        return $decode->data;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

decode.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['token'])) {
require 'JwtHandler.php';
$jwt = new JwtHandler();

$data =  $jwt->jwtDecodeData(trim($_GET['token']));

if(isset($data->id) && isset($data->name) && isset($data->email)):
    echo "<ul>
    <li>ID => $data->id</li>
    <li>Name => $data->name</li>
    <li>Email => $data->email</li>
    </ul>";
else:
    print_r($data);
endif;
}
?>
<form action="" method="GET">
<label for="_token"><strong>Enter Token</strong></label>
<input type="text" name="token" id="_token">
<input type="submit" value="Docode">
</form>
```

i did some research and i found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72310650/19663907

but i am not sure where to place the new instance of Key class, and where to use on the decode method (it is my first time working with JWT so be patient with me :) )

Comment: *but i am not sure where to place the new instance of Key class, and where to use on the decode method* - the linked answer shows exactly how to do it: `JWT::decode($token, new Key($topSecret, 'HS256'));`

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

change the version of "firebase/php-jwt" from:

```
"require": {
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^6.3"
}
```

to:

```
"require": {
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.5.1"
}
```

Comment: Changing from version 6.3 to 5.5 of a library seems like a major downgrade. It might solve your specific problem in the short term but is seldom good as general advice, as you'll also be stuck on this version. There might have been some breaking changes in the newer versions and some reasons for these changes, and you might have to adapt your code to these changes, but that's a part of the programmer's work.