# Getting following error "message": "\"kid\" empty, unable to lookup correct key", when trying to authorize JWT using Bearer

Tags: php, json, jwt, decode, encode

Getting following error  "message": ""kid" empty, unable to lookup correct key", when trying to authorize JWT using Bearer. See coding classes below. I am using postman and php for this. Trying to resolve this issue as I am new to using JWT.

JwtHandler

```
<?php
require './vendor/autoload.php';

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;


class JwtHandler{

    protected $jwt_secret;
    protected $token;
    protected $issuedAt;
    protected $expired;
    protected$jwt;

    public function __construct(){
        //default time zone
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        $this->issuedAt=time();

        //token valid for
        $this->expired=$this->issuedAt + 3600;

        //set secret key
        $this->jwt_secret='8mw37mn_1)$xjg=)$%5-eavqjo6+=yj3gma0-xwl0%5e7he9e';

    }

    public function jwtEncodeData($iss,$data){
        $this->token =array(
            //Adding identifier who issued token
            "iss"=>$iss,
            "aud"=>$iss,
            //Addingcurrent timestamp to token, when it was issue
            "iat"=>$this->issuedAt,
            //Token expiration
            "exp"=>$this->expired,
            //Payload
            "data"=>$data

        );
        $this->jwt=JWT::encode($this->token, $this->jwt_secret, 'HS256');
        return $this->jwt;

    }


    public function jwtDecodeData($jwt_token){
        try{
            $decode = JWT::decode($jwt_token, $this->jwt_secret, array('HS256'));
            return[
                "data" => $decode->data
                ];
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return[
                "message" => $e->getMessage()
                ];
        }

    }

}

?>
```

AuthMiddleware

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/classes/JwtHandler.php';

class Auth extends JwtHandler
{
    protected $db;
    protected $headers;
    protected $token;

    public function __construct($db, $headers)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->headers = $headers;
    }

    public function isValid()
    {

        if (array_key_exists('Authorization', $this->headers) && preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $this->headers['Authorization'], $matches)) {

            $data = $this->jwtDecodeData($matches[1]);

            if (
                isset($data['data']->user_id) &&
                $user = $this->fetchUser($data['data']->user_id)
            ) :
                return [
                    "success" => 1,
                    "user" => $user,
                ];
            else :
                return [
                    "success" => 0,
                    "message" => $data['message'],
                ];
            endif;
         } else {
            return [
                "success" => 0,
                "message" => "Token not found in request",
            ];
        }
    }

    protected function fetchUser($user_id)
    {
        try {
            $fetch_user_by_id = "SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `id`=:id";
            $query_stmt = $this->db->prepare($fetch_user_by_id);
            $query_stmt->bindValue(':id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query_stmt->execute();

            if ($query_stmt->rowCount()) :
                return $query_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            else :
                return false;
            endif;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

getUser

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");


//Calling DB CONNECTION
require __DIR__ . '/classes/Database.php';
require __DIR__ . '/AuthMiddleware.php';

//Checking token valid
$allHeaders = getallheaders();
$db_connection = new Database();
$conn = $db_connection->dbConnection();
$auth = new Auth($conn, $allHeaders);

echo json_encode($auth->isValid());

?>
```

I have tried changing signature values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is JWT::decode() returning { "status": "\"kid\" empty, unable to lookup correct key" }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278051/why-is-jwtdecode-returning-status-kid-empty-unable-to-lookup-corr)

Comment: unfortunately not.