# "Didn't find publicKey for specified kid" error occurs when deploy spring boot to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, keycloak

I am using Keycloak to secure my rest api

I have 2 clients in Keycloak:

-My front-end: React app

-My back-end: Spring boot (bearer only type)

Everything works properly when I run spring boot application.
But I got the error 401 "Didn't find publicKey for specified kid" 
when I run it in tomcat.
Some configuration below:

keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "pet",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "secure-api",
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "enable-cors" : true,
  "cors-max-age" : 1000,
  "cors-allowed-methods" : "POST, PUT, DELETE, GET",
  "cors-exposed-headers" : "WWW-Authenticate, My-custom-exposed-Header"
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <module-name>myapp</module-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Authors</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/management/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>pet</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

context.xml

```
<Context path="/myapp">
    <Valve className="org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve"/>
</Context>
```

keycloak-7.0 and tomcat-8

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

Be aware of your default signature algorithm token configured in KC admin dashboard:

[image]

HS256 required public key in http://{domain}:8080/auth/realms/{realm-name}/.well-known/openid-configuration, unfortunately somehow It's not there. And then “Didn't find publicKey for specified kid” error occured

FYI: [RS256 vs HS256: What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239051/rs256-vs-hs256-whats-the-difference)

**Make sure public key in The OIDC metadata endpoint if you use HS256**

or **Using other Algorithm**