# if (!options.algorithms) throw new Error('algorithms should be set'); Error: algorithms should be set

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, express-jwt

I started learning Nodejs and i am stuck somewhere in the middle. I installed a new library from npm  and that was **express-jwt**, its showing some kind of error after running. Attached the code and the logs of the error, please help me out!

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config()
const expressJwt =  require('express-jwt');
const User = require('../models/user');




exports.requireSignin =  expressJwt({ secret:  process.env.JWT_SECRET});
```

The below thing is  the logs of the error.

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
D:\shubh\proj\Nodejs\nodeapi\node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:22
  if (!options.algorithms) throw new Error('algorithms should be set');
                           ^

**Error: algorithms should be set**
    at module.exports (D:\shubh\proj\Nodejs\nodeapi\node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:22:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\shubh\proj\Nodejs\nodeapi\controllers\auth.js:64:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
```

Comment: For those wondering... The old default was apparently ['HS256']
I changed some legacy code to that as per Igor's answer and it worked without breaking anything. YMMV

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You should add algorithms property to the jwt constructor.

Example;

```
expressJwt({ secret:  process.env.JWT_SECRET, algorithms: ['RS256'] });
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but can you tell me how do we decide which algo to choose.

Comment: It changes on the purpose, if you want to use it for session, you can use HSXXX types. If you want to use it for cross application authentication(like oauth) etc., you can prefer RSXXX types. RS types are digital signatures, HS types are not.

Comment: @Shubhamgupta I would recommend you to read this for understanding the difference between the two algorithms better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39239395/12404524

Answer (score 30):

The issue caused by [changes](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt/commit/304a1c5968aed7c4c520035426fc09142156669d) in version 6.0.0.
[Documentation](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#required-parameters) also has been updated recently, it says:

> The algorithms parameter is required to prevent potential downgrade
> attacks when providing third party libraries as secrets.

So now specifying algorithm property is mandatory, like so:

```js
expressJwt({
  secret: 'secret',
  algorithms: ['HS256']
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this — I was seeing in the docs that `HS256` was the default algo, so I was confused as to why I needed to specify it. Turns out the docs on npm haven't been updated yet.

Comment: Thank you. I was searching for the default algo.

Answer (score 4):

if the above **algorithm : ['RS256']** does not work try this, **algorithms: ['HS256']**

Answer (score 1):

if you are facing this error you might be using the new version of 'express-jwt'
Downgrade to ^5.3.3 version to solve this

Comment: Downgrade, should be always the last solution.

Comment: Non breaking changes and/or proper documentation about managing the transition in a non breaking way should be the first solution for the people managing the package.

Answer (score 1):

```
 exports.requireSignin = expressJwt ({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      algorithms: YOU CHOOSE ALGORITHM 
});
```

For more details visit:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt

```
jwt({ secret: new Buffer('shhhhhhared-secret', 'base64') })
```

Answer (score 1):

*For those wandering what algorithm is used to generate their tokens*

A JWT is made of 3 parts separated with a dot '**.**':

```
<header>.<payload>.<signature>
```

The header (and payload) is just a Base64 encoded JSON object that holds the name of the hashing algorithm.

For example, with that token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtZXNzYWdlIjoiaGkgc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdyJ9.01jBDw7uUgCr8cRMEQt4KJxfL6QLkt0ZuHly2AxdXZY
```

you could use [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) in the javascript console of your browser to decode the header:

```js
atob('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9')
// → "{\"alg\":\"HS256\",\"typ\":\"JWT\"}"
```

Here HS256 was used.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. If you are attempting to provide more context to an already provided answer, maybe that would be better handled as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I had to face the same error, and after I mentioned the algorithm in express-jwt initialization, the error was gone.

Example Code:

```
exports.requireSignin=  expressJwt({
      secret: process.env.jwtSecret,
      userProperty: "auth",
      algorithms: ["RS256"],
    }
```